# Entire functions of finite order with prescribed zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following the problem.

Let $f$ be an entire function of finite order that has roots at all points $z$ such that $e^{e^z}=1$. Prove that $f\equiv 0$.

My idea is argue by contradiction, suppose $f$ is not a constant and consider the function $h(z) = \frac{f(z)}{e^{e^z}-1}$. I want to show that $h$ is a constant, then $f$ is a multiple of $e^{e^z}-1$ and has infinite order. But I'm stuck here now and actually I don't know if this works. There might be such an $f$ with infinite order but not a multiple of $e^{e^z}-1$.

Do we have some results about two functions share the same (or partial) zeros?

Comment: A naive thought, not explored by me, would be to try to explicitly identify in the first instance the set of $z$ for which $e^{(e^z)} = 1$, or at least an infinite subset of that set that has an accumulation point somewhere. I do not see how this naive observation makes use of the 'finite order' assumption.

Comment: For example $f=e^z(e^{e^z}-1)$ works so $h$ is not a constant in general; also the hypothesis doesn't preclude $f$ to have other roots btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{e^z}=1$ means $e^z=2k\pi i$ which means $z=\log (2|k|\pi)\pm \pi i/2+2m\pi i, k,m \in \mathbb Z, k \ne 0$ where the sign is plus if $k>0$ and minus if $k<0$

In particular, if we fix $R>0$ large one can choose $m=0, 1\le k \le \frac{e^{R-\pi/2}}{2\pi}$ and get a root as above so we get at least $Ce^R$ roots; however a function of order $\rho$ has at most $C_{\epsilon}R^{\rho+\epsilon}$ roots of absolute value at most $R$ so contradiction!

Answer (score 2):

$e^{e^{z}}=1$ iff $z=\ln(2k\pi)+(2l\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})i, k\in \mathbb{N}^{*},l\in \mathbb{Z}$.

We will use Theorem 2.1 (ii) in Ch5 of Stein and Shakarchi's complex analysis.

Suppose $f$ is not the zero function and the order of $f$ is $\rho$. Then
$\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{|\ln(2k\pi)+\frac{\pi}{2}|}^{s}}$ converges for all $s>\rho$. But [we know](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand) this series diverges for all $s>0$. Hence $f=0$.